# Delete record from a datagrid view

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Please help me. I added a delete method in the check printing system that i'm creating, before it was working well, but when I changed the data type of the field `Check_Number` from `text` to `number` from their respective tables, it is no longer deleting the data row that i select. i do not remember changing any code from the delete section. do u guys have any idea how to solve this? thank you in advance. More power!

The different Bank_[BankName] has the ff fields and data types:

```
ID - AutoNumber 
Check_Number - Number
Company_ID - Text
```

My `VN_ZAM` table has the ff fields and datatypes:

```
ID - AutoNumber
Voucher_Number - Number
Check_Number - Text
Bank_Type - Text
Company_ID - Text
```

My `SS` table has the ff fields and datatypes (this is also where the data in the datagrid view is taken from):

```
ID - AutoNumber
Check_No - Text
Voucher_No - Text
Issue_Date - Date/Time
Company_Name - Text
Bank_Type - Text 
Amount_in_Figure - Number
Amount_in_Words - Text
Payee - Text
```

My datagridview order looks like this:

```
ID | Check_No | Voucher_No | Issue_Date | Company_Name |Bank_Type | Amount_in_Figure | Amount_in_Words | Payee
```

.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim sql As String
    Dim sql1 As String
    Dim sql2 As String
    Dim answer As Integer

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Information")
    'If answer = vbYes Then
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\bankCheckSystem\dbcheckprintsystem.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    sql = "DELETE * FROM SS WHERE ID =" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()

    If dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(12).Value.ToString() = "ZAM" Then
        sql1 = "DELETE * FROM VN_ZAM WHERE Company_ID = '" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString() & "_" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "' "
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection)
        Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql1, myConnection)

        'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString() = "BDO" Then
            sql2 = "DELETE * FROM Bank_BDO WHERE Company_ID = '" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString() & "_" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "' AND Check_Number ='" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString() & "'"
            Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql2, myConnection)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ElseIf dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value.ToString() = "BPI" Then
            sql2 = "DELETE * FROM Bank_BPI WHERE Company_ID = '" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString() & "_" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "' AND Check_Number ='" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString() & "'"
            Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql2, myConnection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End if

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Delete *" syntax. Can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by you're not familiar with "Delete" syntax, but it's a query I use to delete permanently a record from the database. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-delete-query.htm Thanks. @Strawberry

Comment: That's `"DELETE"`, not `"DELETE *"`

Answer (score 0):

As Strawberry alludes to, I can't find any examples of `DELETE * FROM` being valid syntax (I'm not sure you can use it like `SELECT * FROM` ?). Also if the `Check_Number` in the Bank tables has changed to `number`, I'm not sure you need the single quotes around the values. Does it help if you change your four SQL statements to the following?

1. `sql = "DELETE FROM SS WHERE ID = " & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()`
2. `sql1 = "DELETE FROM VN_ZAM WHERE Company_ID = '" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString() & "_" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "' "`
3. `sql2 = "DELETE FROM Bank_BDO WHERE Company_ID = '" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString() & "_" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "' AND Check_Number = " & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()`
4. `sql2 = "DELETE FROM Bank_BPI WHERE Company_ID = '" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(4).Value.ToString() & "_" & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "' AND Check_Number = " & dgvSSCheckRecords.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString()`